# Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Tags: php, string

I get above error on my php code. I get the error for the following line.

```
 echo '<tr><td style="width:400px;padding:5px;"></td><td style="width:300px;padding:5px;"><img src="'.$image_folder.$value->$value->prfil_img .'" /></td></tr>';
```

I know I haven't use strings properly here. Either double quotation or single quotation have not been used properly. However, I can't figure it out.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Your quotations look fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks wrong:

```
$image_folder.$value->$value->prfil_img
```

You probably meant:

```
$image_folder . $value->prfil_img
```

Comment: +1 The second $value is being converted to a string so it can be interpreted as a variable property, Hence the error

Comment: thanks lot, without your help I won't figure this out. I used to always look in to quatations when I get this kind of error. thanks for so too.